# Google Script get PDF document dimensions

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

Is there a way I can retrieve the document dimensions of a PDF file using Google Scripts?

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no mention of fetching the PDF dimensions in Apps Script [Drive Files](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file). There's only PAGE_HEIGHT and PAGE_HEIGHT E

Check: [Attribute for documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/attribute)